# How to write a Vss provider code that copy block changes

Tags: windows-server-2008, volume-shadow-service

I want to write a Vss provider code that save the block changes to a volume 
Where can I find information about this?
The example I have found on Internet performed only full copy of all data when a snapshot were requested

Comment: There is no change block tracking on volume level in Windows even though it is mentioned in the documents

Comment: It is actually a filesystem snapshot technique instead.